# Customize month names in MUI DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

Is there any way to change the month name format from 3 words to full name?

[this is what i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkxfn.png)

for example mui responsive datepicker shows:

Jan - Feb - Mar - Apr - May

I want it to be like January - February - March and so on.

I've already localized date picker to Jalali but it only displays first 3 words of the month name.

```
 <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterJalali}>
  <DatePicker
    PopperProps={{
      sx: popperSx,
    }}
    open={isForcePickerOpen}
    onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
    components={{
      OpenPickerIcon: "a",
    }}
    className="relative"
    disableFuture
    label="Responsive"
    minDate={minDate ? moment(minDate, "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate() : undefined}
    maxDate={maxDate ? moment(maxDate, "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate() : undefined}
    openTo="year"
    views={views}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    renderInput={({ inputRef, inputProps, InputProps }) => (
      <div
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        onTouchStart={() => setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen)}
        onClick={() => setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen)}
        ref={inputRef}
        {...inputProps}
        className="relative flex flex-row justify-between p-2 h-14 items-center text-immigoTextGray
                       border-1 border-gray-400 w-full rounded-lg  "
      >
        <input
          readOnly
          className="absolute disabled -z-30"
          disabled
          hidden
        />
        {/* {InputProps?.endAdornment} */}
        <span className="font-dana-regular text-xs">{label}</span>

        <span className=" px-2 font-dana-regular text-base text-gray-800">
          {faData}
        </span>
        <CalendarMonthIcon />

        {/* <div  >
          </div>
         <div  className='disabled'>
          
         </div> */}
      </div>
    )}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  It would be helpful to see code that can be reproduced so that we can better help you.  If you update your question to include some code, you will probably get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ckesplin thank you! I've included some of the codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need add dateFormats To display the full name of the month.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterJalali} dateFormats={{ monthShort: 'MMMM' }}>
  // datepicker
</LocalizationProvider>
```